# My react app is giving an error of "action undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My react app when ever I start my react app it gives an error of action undefined. Which I used in my reducer in switch(action.type) and I am getting the issue I searched for it but the syntax was the same or maybe I am doing mistake somewhere else but I am unable to figure it out.

Action.js

```
export function createUser(details)
{
return{ type: 'CREATE_USER',details}
}
```

Reducer.js

```
export default function userReducer(state= initialState, action) {
switch (action.type) {
    case 'CREATE_USER':
        return[...state,
            Object.assign({}, action.details)

        ];
    default:
        return state;
   }
}
```

index.js form combine reducers

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import userReducer from './Reducers';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   detail: userReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

ConfigureStore.js

```
import rootReducer from "../reducers/index";
import {createStore} from 'redux';

export default function (initialState) {
    return createStore(
        initialState,
        rootReducer,
    )
 }
```

Comment: Are you creating the store somewhere in your app by passing the combined reducer: `Redux.createStore(combineReducers(...), initialState`?

Comment: yup just edited the question and added it

Comment: but its not the way you said it a bit different i guess ! :D

Comment: The reducer has to be the first argument to `createStore`(see [here](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) and [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/initializingstate)). Try `return createStore(rootReducer, initialState)`.

Comment: yup, arguments are not in place!

Comment: I don't get it a bit confused can you explain a little ?

Comment: @SaifKhan you passed the arguments in the wrong order. You call `createStore(initialState, rootReducer)` when it should be `createStore(rootReducer, initialState)`.

Comment: Okay and it worked thank you !

Comment: @SaifKhan Great! I posted an answer, in case you want to officially accept the solution.

Comment: Yup sure why not !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you need to reverse the order in which you pass `initialState` and `rootReducer` to `createStore`: i.e. change your *ConfigureStore.js* to

```
import rootReducer from "../reducers/index";
import { createStore } from 'redux';

export default function (initialState) {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
    )
 }
```